# Declaring class handle as rand type in System Verilog

Tags: class, sorting, random, constraints, system-verilog

[Please See this for better clarification of of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYkOd.png)What happens when we declare class handle as rand type?
will it affect the randomization?
I am trying to do sorting using constraint guards.

```
class Sorting;
    rand int unsigned n;
    rand Sorting next;
    constraint C0 { n inside {[2:20]};}

    constraint sort {if( next != null ) n < next.n;}

endclass

module random;
  Sorting s;
  initial
    begin
      s=new;
      repeat(10)
        begin
          assert(s.randomize());
          $write("%0d\t",s.n);
        end
    end
endmodule
```

I am getting the warning in VCS like these -> Warning-[CNST-PPRW] Constraint randomize NULL object warning

The same code is in the LRM under the constraint guard section. I am curious to know whether we can sort the random data using the constraint guard technique? I have done sorting the random data using foreach loop inside the constraint. I am just trying this way. Help me with it.
Thanks!

Comment: what does `rand Sorting` even mean in your case. What did you expect? random new?  remove `rand` from there.

Comment: Thanks Serge! ...But I have the same question about it. So when I run the code by removing the rand before the handle next, the code is running fine but constraints sort dose not working my outputs were just random values between 2-20. My actual intention is to have a sorted output . It was given in the system Verilog 2017 LRM under the constraint guards topic of  Randomization chapter. the same code with class handle as a rand type. So I had tried to figure out why they mentioned in the LRM?

Comment: If I am doing it wrongly please guide me. I am following the Language reference Manual to get know about the stuff that is written in it. Thanks

Comment: you need to explain better what you are trying to achieve. 'sorting' and 'random' are just completely opposite parts of the spectrum. Sorted means no random and vice versa. My guess is that you try to create an array of random numbers between 2 and 20 and sort them then. if so, you need to think over your algorithm.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I respect your views regarding my doubt. To be honest, I can sort my data with any other algorithm, and it will be better for me too. I have done using foreach loop inside the constraint as well. What I want to do here is that my variable n should be a randomly generated number and I want that random numbers should appear in an ascending. It's not that I have got this idea to sort random data. I didn't able to get why they had mentioned this in the LRM.

Comment: The first part of the code i.e from **class to endclass** , is mention in the LRM, so I tried it out the way it is mentioned but could not able to get it because I am not getting the intended output.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. According to the LRM this should not produce any warning.

VCS produces a warning, which it should not. At least it is not an error and you can safely ignore it. There might be a way to turn the warning off, if you wish. Check command line switches.

BTW, NC does not produce any warning.